# Xamarin Live Player iOS DisplayActionSheet/Alert

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am currently trying out Xamarin Live Player for iOS, working on Windows 10 Visual Studio.

I have a question concerning DisplayActionSheet. **Could it be that Xamarin Live Player can't show ActionSheets or Alerts currently?** I couldn't find something about this topic on the page for the Xamarin Live Player limitations. On the Android Emulator it is working fine and as expected, so I guess the code is correct.

Thanks for your help!

Best regards, 
Markus

Comment: can't show? did you get any error. Please explain your problem

Comment: Could you provide specific detail to describe the problem?

Comment: The problem is the following: I have a button on a ContentPage. When I click on this button, the DisplayActionSheet should appear. When I run it in the Android Emulator, it works fine. When I run it on my iPhone via Xamarin Live Player, the button is clickable, but the DisplayActionSheet isn't showing up. There is no error. Not at building nor during running the app.