# DisplayAlert not showing during changes in variable

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Main Page**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        btnStartGame.Clicked += btnStartGame_Clicked;
    }
    public async void btnStartGame_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalVariables globalVar = new GlobalVariables();
        globalVar.CurrentSeconds = 20;
        StartPage startPage = new StartPage();
        startPage.setGlobalVariables(globalVar);
        await Navigation.PushAsync(startPage);
    }
}
```

**Start Page**

```
public partial class StartPage : ContentPage
{
    GlobalVariables globalVar;
    public StartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = globalVar;
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    }
    public void setGlobalVariables(GlobalVariables globalVar)
    {
        this.globalVar = globalVar;
    }
    private void btnSample_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        globalVar.CurrentSeconds++;
        DisplayAlert("AW", globalVar.CurrentSeconds.ToString(), "AW");
    }
}
```

**GlobalVariables.cs**

```
public class GlobalVariables : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _currentSeconds;
    public int CurrentSeconds
    {
        get { return _currentSeconds; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentSeconds != value)
            {
                _currentSeconds = value;
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await FingerSmash2.App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("AW", "AW", "AW");
                });
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

With this codes, every time `btnSample_Clicked` runs, the `set{}` in `CurrentSeconds` will also fire. But the problem is, the `DisplayAlert` inside `set{}` does not fire at all, only the `DisplayAlert` inside `btnSample_Clicked`.

How to also fire the `DisplayAlert` inside `set{}`? Or if not possible, is there a way to fire an event in **Start Page** from **GlobalVariables**?

Comment: might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46690454/4610605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine.

As described in [Xamarin Live Player iOS DisplayActionSheet/Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690454/xamarin-live-player-ios-displayactionsheet-alert?noredirect=1&lq=1) it may be related to the **Xamarin Live Player**.

Deploying your app on an device or even the emulator should ensure if your code is correct or not !